# Quickblox: upload image REST API

Tags: rest, quickblox

http://quickblox.com/developers/Content#Upload_a_file

when i post my form(encode=multipart/form-data action=params field from the response of file creation.. something like "http://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIY7KFM23XGXJ7R7A&Policy=eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDEyLTA0LTIzVDE0OjIyOjM0WiIsCiAgICAgICJjb25kaXRpb25zIjogWwogICAgICAgIHsiYnVja2V0IjogInFicHJvZCJ9LAogICAgICAgIFsiZXEiLCAiJGtleSIsICIzMGE4YmNkN2M3MTQ0MTdlYjYyYjk1MzUwZDdlMTNiOTAwIl0sCiAgICAgICAgeyJhY2wiOiAiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZC1yZWFkIn0sCiAgICAgICAgWyJlcSIsICIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlL2pwZWciXSwKICAgICAgICB7InN1Y2Nlc3NfYWN0aW9uX3N0YXR1cyI6ICIyMDEifQogICAgICBdCiAgICB9&Signature=eBtgK1jAzsGNcFjpqEGiTLnm008%3D&key=30a8bcd7c714417eb62b95350d7e13b900&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&acl=authenticated-read&success_action_status=201" + Expires field.

Response is:
 ... The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. ...

what im doing wrong?
can anyone help me with uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a POST request from this string:

```
    POST http://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com
       AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIY7KFM23XGXJ7R7A
       Policy=eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDEyLTA0LTIzVDE0OjIyOjM0WiIsCiAgICAgICJjb25kaXRpb25zIjogWwogICAgICAgIHsiYnVja2V0IjogInFicHJvZCJ9LAogICAgICAgIFsiZXEiLCAiJGtleSIsICIzMGE4YmNkN2M3MTQ0MTdlYjYyYjk1MzUwZDdlMTNiOTAwIl0sCiAgICAgICAgeyJhY2wiOiAiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZC1yZWFkIn0sCiAgICAgICAgWyJlcSIsICIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlL2pwZWciXSwKICAgICAgICB7InN1Y2Nlc3NfYWN0aW9uX3N0YXR1cyI6ICIyMDEifQogICAgICBdCiAgICB9
       Signature=eBtgK1jAzsGNcFjpqEGiTLnm008=
       key=30a8bcd7c714417eb62b95350d7e13b900
       Content-Type=image/jpeg
       acl=authenticated-read
       success_action_status=201
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters</Message><RequestId>EC4132679E493D35</RequestId><HostId>ifnV//lBE8Yje+7WdeOVv1TyTP59RxY0XqTNWWy7WKtqzYolDk7Lj56Gy+YSBkB2</HostId></Error>   what now? why the manual does not say anything about the Expires field?

Comment: you have to properly make a request, nothing more

Comment: Where do we have to put the blob file in the request? The doc doesn't say anything about it. I mean the actual binary of the content